# Does every document loaded in Marklogic have document properties?

Tags: marklogic

Today I got a strange output from the MarkLogic query console. The ML query console returned an empty query sequence when I tried to get document properties of a document that already exists in the MarkLogic Database.

This returned a document:

```
 fn:doc("/rooturi/abcd.xml")
```

... and this time it returned an empty sequence:

```
 xdmp:document-properties("/rooturi/abcd.xml")
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, documents don't have properties by default. You can add them with `xdmp:document-set-properties()` or `xdmp:document-add-properties()`. Check out http://docs.marklogic.com/ for details.

Note that you can also only have properties with no corresponding document, something that is called "**naked properties**".

Comment: Worth noting that if you're using CPF or a small number of other features, you do get properties fragments, but none of those features are on by default.

Comment: Worth noting as well is that it is usually considered a good thing that documents don't always have properties. Properties are stored in a separate fragment, which is waste of disk space if you are not using those properties. Sometimes people go as far as maintaining timestamps themselves within the doc, just to prevent the need for properties fragments, and save disk space (and probably memory as well)..

Answer (score 1):

Also note that if you create '**directory nodes**' either explicitly or by the database setting those are actually property documents. (one per directory).

Besides **CPF** some other toolkits and features make use of properties such as the **DLS** (Library Services) and '**maintain last modification**'

See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_93323 for information on database settings that will implicitly create property nodes.